# Close event not triggered in renderer process, but other events are fine

Tags: javascript, electron

This question is about Electron.

In my renderer process, I have

```
const {remote} = require('electron')
remote.getCurrentWindow().on('close', (e) => {
  // some work
});
```

The code inside the callback function will never be called when I click the close button on the window title bar.

However, if I change `'close'` to something else (such as `'resize'`, `'minimize'`), the callback function will be called (when I resize the window, or click on the minimize button).

What could be the cause for this strange behavior?

I am using Electron 1.4.0 on Mac OS X 10.12.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of this. How can I forget about these important details when I seek for help. I'll add it to the question right now.

Comment: Does the 'closed' event work properly?

Comment: It works, but I need to call a method that depends on the window's existence. So `closed` would be too late for my case. I'll probably draw my own close buttons to hack this...

Comment: That's weird. If that's the case, your last bet would be to trying to attach an event handler for the `close` event on the main process.

Comment: I would suggest putting the event handler for `close` into the main process, `remote` can be unreliable when dealing with events.